# Is having only one Form Type Class for one entity better than having multiple Form Type Classes?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

suppose I have a few places on web where I want to update specific fields on entity. For example for changing user password I have one route and for changing user details (like where is he from) another one. Which practice is better? Having only one Form Type class for rendering specific form fields via form_row? Or is it better to have multiple Form Type classes with different options in form builder?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the Single responsability principle,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

UserDetailsType, ChangePasswordType...

every class (form class in this case) should be used for a single purpose, all of them can have as `data_class` the entity of course but for an specific use.

In case that you have two classes that are doing exactly the same thing but maybe just one field is missing you can do

`$builder->remove('field')`

after setting the parent, but it has to be a really specific case...